# Height of male population following Normal Distribution, and 2 simple questions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, normal-distribution

Let the distribution of height among a male population be given by $X \sim N(μ = 175, σ = 5) \rightarrow f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}}{e^{\frac{-(x-175)^2}{2\times5^2}}}$.

We choose 6 of them.

1. What is the probability of them being above $180cm$ in height (A)?
2. What is the probability of having 2 above the mean height, and the other 4 below the mean (B)?

My try for both is:

1. Firstly I will find the probability of the height being bigger than $180cm$, so $P(x > 180) = 1- \Phi(\frac{180-175}{5}) = 1 - \Phi(1) = 1 - 0.84 = 0.16$. Then we want to have only successes, $6$ in number, so the probability of A is $P(A) = 0.16^6$
2. Firstly I will find the probability of the height being bigger than $180cm$, so $P(x < 175) = \Phi(\frac{175-175}{5}) = 1 - \Phi(0) = 1 - 0.5 = 0.5$. Then out of $6$, we want $2$ successes and $4$ failures (letting the selection being independent, and as $p = 1 - p$, so we only have 2 outcomes) so: $\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} 0.5^20.5^4 = 0.23$ via the Binomial Distribution

Have I made any mistake? Thanks for your time =)

Comment: Your answer is correct.